# Removing Index from Activerecord object Not from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have to fetch the records from the database and after some validations i have to remove the record from the object if the custom validation get failed.

@posts = Post.all

After doing some business logic validation i don't want to keep post with id 1 only in the @posts object How can i remove that post from the @posts object only not from the database.

Comment: why you don't just ignore the post with id 1?

Comment: as i am not sure about the business logic validation where it will be failed. any how I figured out the answer We can delete as the following: @posts = Posts.all and delete the index 0 with the following @posts.delete_at(0)

Comment: Your code seems to be very strange. I'm not sure you use the better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the select method:

```
@posts.select do |post| 
  post.id == 1 
  #or any custom validation that returns true in case you want to keep the record 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to delete the record only from array of activerecord results and not database try this

```
#first convert the @post to array

@post.to_a.delete_if{|post| post.id == 1 }
```

this will delete the post with id = 1 (only from array not from database)

or

```
#pass the object to delete

post = @post.first
@post.to_a.delete(post)
```

this will delete the matching post (only from array not from database)

You can also use Array#reject but that would create a new array so I go with the above solution.

+1 for the question :)